# How to do data augmentation with tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow, data-augmentation, tensorflow-federated

I'm hoping to explore how data augmentation work on federated learning, and I'm currently using tff to implement it. I notice that the datasets provide by tff is composed of tensors, and tensors cannot be adjusted directly, so a naive idea would be to change it to numpy arrays and then do augmentation. I tried

`tfds.as_numpy(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(n))`
and it did provided me with numpy arrays, but I got problems when trying to pass it to preprocess functions. If I do:
`preprocess(tfds.as_numpy(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(n)))`

where preprocess is defined as

```
def preprocess(dataset):

    def batch_format_fn(element):
        """Flatten a batch `pixels` and return the features as an `OrderedDict`."""

        return collections.OrderedDict(
            x=tf.reshape(element['pixels'], [-1, 784]),
            y=tf.reshape(element['label'], [-1, 1]))

    return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(
        BATCH_SIZE).map(batch_format_fn).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)
```

I would get the following error:

```
return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(
AttributeError: '_IterableDataset' object has no attribute 'repeat'
```

which seems to mean that this **_IterableDataset** object of numpy arrays cannot be applied for these methods.

And I tried wrapping `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` method as `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tfds.as_numpy(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(n)))`, but it ends up with this error:

`ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_utils._IterableDataset object at 0x00000280AA695DF0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_utils._IterableDataset'>) to a Tensor.`

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or could I do augmentation just on the data it provides?

#### Updates

It would be enough to just use `map` function if I only want to convert each sample in the dataset to a augmented one. However, if I want to add new samples to the dataset(e.g. adding samples of different labels), how can I do it? Since we can't modify the client dataset directly, I was thinking converting it to a numpy array and make further processing, yet if I do:

`state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, tfds.as_numpy(federated_train_data))`
where `federated_train_data` is a client dataset, I got

`TypeError: Expected tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV2 or tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1, found tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_utils._IterableDataset.`

Seems this `_IterableDataset` couldn't be applied to the process. Is there a way that I can convert this dataset back to what is acceptable by `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process()`? Or is there a better way to do this kind of augmentation?

#### Update 2

I was trying to use a generator from a GAN model to generate new images to augment the dataset.  I have a pretrained GAN (written by tf.keras), and I wrote a dataGenerator to wrap this model for augmenting the client datasets. However, when I do the fed-avg training, the following error occurred:

```
  File "D:\Research\GAN_AUG_FL\utils\augment_utils.py", line 53, in generate_once
    generated_images = generator(generator_input)
  File "D:\Research\GAN_AUG_FL\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 665, in __call__
    self._assert_built_as_v1()
  File "D:\Research\GAN_AUG_FL\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py", line 836, in _assert_built_as_v1
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Your Layer or Model is in an invalid state. This can happen for the following cases:
 1. You might be interleaving estimator/non-estimator models or interleaving models/layers made in tf.compat.v1.Graph.as_default() with models/layers created outside of it. Converting a model to an estimator (via model_to_estimator) invalidates all models/layers made before the conversion (even if they were not the model converted to an estimator). Similarly, making a layer or a model inside a a tf.compat.v1.Graph invalidates all layers/models you previously made outside of the graph.
2. You might be using a custom keras layer implementation with  custom __init__ which didn't call super().__init__.  Please check the implementation of <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'> and its bases.
```

Here `generator` is just the keras model for generation. I suspect this is because in tff the computation graph is different from the one I used to create an instance of the generator model. The code for training is just like the toturial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification).

```
emnist_train, emnist_test = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data(only_digits=True, cache_dir="data/emnist")

example_dataset = emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(emnist_train.client_ids[0])
example_dataset = preprocess(example_dataset)

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model,
        input_spec=example_dataset.element_spec,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    )


iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
)

state = iterative_process.initialize()

# state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, [example_dataset])
# print('round  1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))


for round_num in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
    selected_clients = random.sample(emnist_train.client_ids, 1)
    federated_data = [
        preprocess(emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(n))
        for n in selected_clients
    ]
    state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_data)
    print(f"round  {round_num + 1}, metrics={metrics}")
```

But at this point strange things happen if I uncomment the two lines before going into the loop. This time the training could go smoothly, but still reports the same bug after going into the loop. Therefore I guess after the first time this preprocess is done, tff is using some different graph? Is there any possible solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to just do the augmentation directly on the `tf.data.Dataset` objects, using `tf.data.Dataset.map`, following for instance [this TF tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#apply_augmentation_to_a_dataset).

The main reason is that TFF serializes the computations and executes them later, so whatever processing you are doing in Python / numpy, would need to happen beforehand. In principle, you could also load, augment, and save a dataset using py/np, and then provide the augmented dataset to TFF, but that would likely be a complicated workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Seems a augment function via mapping is suitable for it. I got trapped with the idea of doing augmentations over numpy arrays before.

Comment: I was trying to do a different kind of augmentation, this time I cannot do it just by map. Any possible solutions to it?

Comment: From updated Q, I assume you want to add new elements to client's data. This should, too, be done outside of TFF, in `tf.data` manipulation. `tf.data.Dataset.concatenate` might be a good starting point. In general, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data could be a useful read.

Comment: Dataset.concatenate seems to be a good way. Thanks again!

Comment: Still got further problems when deploying another model for generating samples to augment the client dataset. Is it related with the graph setting of tff?